# Making a school management system and getting errors

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to programming and learning the C language and was practising structures and was trying to make basic school management system by using structures, but I am getting
too many errors (by using pointers in structures). So, can you please tell me what are the errors and how can I avoid these types of mistakes. Because, according to my understanding this should have been working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    int rollno;
    char name[20];
    float marks;
};

int main() {
    again:;

    while (1 == 1) {
        struct student array[60];
        char input;
        int roll;
        printf("What you would like to do:\n");
        printf("Enter 'R' to fill the details again of all the student\n Enter 'U' to edit the 
    details of a single student\n");
        printf("Enter 'S' to see the details of a particular student\n Enter 'A' to see the 
    details of every student\n");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        if (input == 'A' || 'a') {
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                printf("Roll no. : %d\n Name : %s\n Marks : %f\n", array[i].rollno, array[i].name, 
     array[i].marks);
            }
        }
        else if (input == 'R' || 'r') {
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                printf("Roll no. os student is : %d\n", (i + 1));
                printf("Enter students name :\n");
                gets(array[i].name);
                printf("Enter students marks :\n");
                scanf("%f", &array[i].marks);
            }
        }
        else if (input == 'S' || 's') {
            printf("Enter the roll no. of the student of whom you want to see the details :\n");
            scanf("%d", &roll);
            printf("Roll no. :\n %d\n", roll);
            printf("Name : \n");
            puts(array[(roll - 1)].name);
            printf("Marks : \n %f \n", (*(array + (roll - 1))->marks));
        }
        else if (input == 'U' || 'u') {
            printf("Enter the roll no. of the student of whom you want to see the details :\n");
            scanf("%d", &roll);
            printf("Enter the name :\n");
            gets((*(array + (roll - 1))->name));
            printf("Enter the marks :\n");
            scanf("%f", &(*(array + (roll + 1))->marks));
        } else {
            printf("Error Occured!!! \n");
            printf("Re-enter your input\n");
            goto again;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always compile your code with compiler warnings enabled, and treat warnings as errors. Throw away the book that taught you to use `gets`. Never use that function, ever, use `fgets` instead. Separate functionality and put them into functions so that you can focus on one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

- there is no need for a `goto again;`, you already have an infinite loop `while (1 == 1)`, which is usually written `for (;;)` in C. Don't use `goto`.
- the definition `struct student array[60];` should be moved outside the scope of the loop body. As posted, the array is discarded after each iteration and its contents become indeterminate.
- `array` should be initialized to avoid undefined behavior when printing the contents before reading it from the user.
- string literals cannot span multiple lines in a C source file. You can split them this way for readability:

  ```
    printf("What you would like to do:\n"
           "Enter 'R' to fill the details again of all the student\n"
           "Enter 'U' to edit the details of a single student\n"
           "Enter 'S' to see the details of a particular student\n"
           "Enter 'A' to see the details of every student\n");
  ```
- you should have a menu option to quit the program
- reading a single character with `scanf("%c", &input)` is tricky: `scanf()` will read the pending newline from a previous call. You should use `scanf(" %c", &input)` where the space will cause pending whitespace to be read and discarded.
- `if (input == 'A' || 'a')` does not test for `A` or `a`, it compares `input` to `'A'` and if different compares `'a'` to zero, hence the test is always true. You should write:

  ```
    if (input == 'A' || input == 'a')
  ```
- `gets(array[i].name);` is a **NO NO**. Don't use `gets()`, throw away the book that tells you to use it. For consistency with the other inputs, you can use

  ```
    scanf("%19[^\n]", array[i].name);
  ```

Note that `19` tells `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store into `array[i].name` before the null terminator, preventing undefined behavior for longer user input, and `[^\n]` causes `scanf()` to read and store characters up to and not including the newline character. `%19s` would stop at any white space, preventing the input of multiple words such as `James Bond`.

- `scanf("%f", &(*(array + (roll + 1))->marks));` is a very contorted way to write:

  ```
    scanf("%f", &array[roll + 1].marks);
  ```
- you should check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input and flush the pending input on error.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    int rollno;
    char name[20];
    float marks;
};

int main() {
    struct student array[60] = { 0 };
    int len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    int c, i, roll;
    char input;

    for (;;) {
        printf("What you would like to do:\n"
               "Enter 'R' to fill the details of all the student\n"
               "Enter 'U' to edit the details of a single student\n"
               "Enter 'S' to see the details of a particular student\n"
               "Enter 'A' to see the details of every student\n"
               "Enter 'Q' to quit the program\n");
        if (scanf(" %c", &input) != 1)
            break;
        if (input == 'A' || input == 'a') {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                printf("Roll no.: %d\nName: %s\nMarks: %f\n",
                       array[i].rollno, array[i].name, array[i].marks);
            }
        } else
        if (input == 'R' || input == 'r') {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                printf("Roll no. os student is: %d\n", i + 1);
                printf("Enter student's name:\n");
                if (scanf("%19[^\n]", array[i].name) != 1)
                    break;
                printf("Enter students marks:\n");
                if (scanf("%f", &array[i].marks) != 1)
                    break;
            }
            if (i < len) {
                printf("Invalid input\n");
            }
        } else
        if (input == 'S' || input == 's') {
            printf("Enter the roll no. of the student of whom you want to see the details:\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &roll) == 1 && roll >= 1 && roll <= len) {
                printf("Roll no.: %d\nName: %s\nMarks: %f\n",
                       roll, array[roll - 1].name, array[roll - 1].marks);
            } else {
                printf("Invalid Roll no\n");
            }
        } else
        if (input == 'U' || input == 'u') {
            printf("Enter the roll no. of the student of whom you want to see the details:\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &roll) == 1 && roll >= 1 && roll <= len) {
                printf("Enter the name:\n");
                scanf("%19[^\n]", array[roll - 1].name);
                printf("Enter the marks:\n");
                scanf("%f", &array[roll - 1].marks);
            } else {
                printf("Invalid Roll no\n");
            }
        } else
        if (input == 'Q' || input == 'q') {
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid entry\n");
            printf("Re-enter your input\n");
        }
        /* read and discard the rest of the input line */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
    }
    printf("Premature end of file\n");
    return 0;
}
```